# I cannot add container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

Hi, I am new to flutter. I cannot add another container after I did the first container. It keeps saying an error. Here is my code for your review.

class UserProfile extends StatelessWidget {
const UserProfile({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(

```
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: Row( 
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
      
      children: [
      Text (' SmartParking '),
        Icon(Icons.directions_car,
         color: Colors.yellow, size: 30),
      ],), ),
  
  
  body: Container(
    child: Padding( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row( 
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget> [ 
                  Column(  
                    children: [ 
                      Icon(Icons.local_parking),
                  Text("Wallet"),
                  Text("RM40.00",
                      style: TextStyle( 
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                        ,
                        ),
                     ],
                  ),
                   Column(  
                    children: [ 
                      Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined),
                      Text("110", 
                  style: TextStyle( 
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    GestureDetector( 
                        onTap: () { 
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocationPage() 
                          ), );
                        },
                      ), 
                    Text ('points',
                    
                    ),
                    ],
                  ),
            ],
              ),
              ),

        
              ),
              
  
                ),
    
               );
```

}
} [image]

Comment: What type of error you faced ??

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: The error message states that it requires a NAMED parameter, not a POSITIONAL parameter. Check that you add the new Container within the square brackets of Row's children, not outside it.

Comment: You add a container in wrong place, add container in column.
Scaffold as only one child, you cannot add more than one child in scaffold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wrap Container` in `Scaffold()`

```
Scaffold(
child: Container(
    child: Padding( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row( 
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget> [ 
                  Column(  
                    children: [ 
                      Icon(Icons.local_parking),
                      Text("Wallet"),
                  Text("RM40.00",
                      style: TextStyle( 
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                     ],
                  ),
                   Column(  
                    children: [ 
                      Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined),
                      Text("110", 
                  style: TextStyle( 
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), 
                    Text ('points',
                    ),
                    ],
                  ),
            ],
              ),
              ));
```

Comment: still get an error

Answer (score -1):

you have wrap your conatiner with column like the below code

```
scaffold(child:Column(children:Container()))
```